# HashMap java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java

i have the following code:

```
public List<String> processMap(Map<String, String> aMap) {
    Cloner cloner = new Cloner();

    Map<String, String> tempMap = cloner.deepClone(aMap);

    while(!tempMap.isEmpty()) {
        Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iterator = tempMap.entrySet().iterator();

        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            Entry<String, String> entry = iterator.next(); // !!!
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

To deep copy the map i use this library: [Cloner](https://code.google.com/p/cloning/)

I marked the line where i unfortunately get a `ava.util.ConcurrentModificationException` with '!!!'

Can you please tell me why i get this exception?

The complete code:

```
    Cloner cloner = new Cloner();

    Map<String, FreebaseType> tempFreebaseTypes = new HashMap<String, FreebaseType>();
    Map<String, FreebaseType> freebaseTypesCopy = cloner.deepClone(freebaseTypes);

    while(!freebaseTypesCopy.isEmpty()) {
        Iterator<Entry<String, FreebaseType>> iterator = freebaseTypesCopy.entrySet().iterator();

        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            Entry<String, FreebaseType> entry = iterator.next();

            if(tempFreebaseTypes.containsKey(entry.getValue().getSuperType()) || entry.getValue().getSuperType() == null) {
                tempFreebaseTypes.put(entry.getValue().getType(), entry.getValue());

                freebaseTypesCopy.remove(entry.getKey());
            } 
        }
    }

    List<FreebaseType> sortedFreebaseTypes = new ArrayList<FreebaseType>();
    Iterator<Entry<String, FreebaseType>> iterator = tempFreebaseTypes.entrySet().iterator();

    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        Entry<String, FreebaseType> entry = iterator.next();

        sortedFreebaseTypes.add(entry.getValue());
    }

    return sortedFreebaseTypes;
```

Comment: Can you pls not abbreviate "please"?

Comment: not sure . some thing like . iterator.remove(obj) in for loop

Comment: I would guess that Cloner clones parts of the implementation of the map which aren't supposed to be cloned which results in a corrupted Map.

Comment: What else is in your while loop? Can you come up with a short but complete program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: are you removing any element from the map inside your iteration loop ?  that can cause concurrent modification exception

Comment: The part where you modify the map is missing.

Comment: adding/removing a new key-value in the HashMap, it will cause ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: but i thought i have to use an iterator to make it possible to modify my map while im iterating? I need to modify it.

Comment: oh you are removing freebaseTypesCopy.remove(entry.getKey());

Comment: When it's a map of `<String, String>` why do you use an external library anyway? You can copy the content of one map into another with `newMap.putAll(originalMap)`

Comment: The original one is not of type `<String, String>` i edited my post. but i thought i have to use an iterator to make it possible to modify my map while im iterating? I need to modify it.

Comment: @Mulgard updating the existing key value in the Map, its size has not been changed then you will not get ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: agree with others, you didn't include the part where you are removing elements from the tempMap.  I only figured it out because you wrote while(!tempMap.isEmpty()) and you wouldn't have used that unless you were removing stuff from the map.

Comment: eeeeaaii i alredy updated my post and i already left some comments.

Comment: @Mulgard It was very misleading that you posted a abbreviated code first where the problem doesn't actually occur because you omitted the actual modification of the map. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you iterate a map with an iterator, you are not allowed to modify the map directly, or you get a `ConcurrentModificationException`. The only way to modify the map is indirectly through the iterators [remove()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29) method, which removes the entry the iterator is currently pointing to from the map.

Replace the line

```
freebaseTypesCopy.remove(entry.getKey());
```

with

```
iterator.remove();
```

and the code should work.

Comment: So how can i actually add/remove elements in my List, Map or whatever while im iterating it? I need to do it.

Comment: As I wrote, you can remove the current element through the iterators remove-method. But you can not add any elements to the currently iterated collection and neither can you remove elements the iterator is not currently pointing to.

Comment: [The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29) says: *"void remove(): Removes from the underlying collection the last element returned by this iterator."* What else do you think this method could do?

Comment: @Mulgard When your program runs in an infinite loop, I would rather suspect a bug in the if-condition before the remove which is never satisfied for some elements, so they won't ever get deleted. That would mean that `while(!freebaseTypesCopy.isEmpty())` will never terminate. Did you trace your code with the debugger?

Comment: @Mulgard Why do you have the remove in the if-condition in the first place? Either you want to remove all elements from `freebaseTypesCopy`, then putting the remove into the if-condition would be pointless, or you don't want to remove all elements, then the `while(!freebaseTypesCopy.isEmpty())` loop would be counter-productive.

Comment: Its complicated. Its all about class structure. which class inerhits from which class. the elements of my map are freebase types and its completly mixed. i later iterate over the map to create all freebase types as classes in my graph database. but i have to kind of "sort" them because when i hava a class "person" which inerhits from "people" i cant create the class "person" before i create the class "people". so i "sort" my map. Thats the point of doing it.